# How to hide text ion-option ionic2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

How to hide text ion-option .
I want to hide or delete some text to show in ion-option. (not delete data)
because I want to save for user choose it

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="refine" (ionChange)="optionsFn(item, i);" >
        <ion-option [value]="item"  *ngFor="let item of totalfilter ;let i = index" >
          {{item["@NAME"]}}
        </ion-option>
      </ion-select>
```

and

```
this.totalfilter = data.json().FACETLIST.FACET;
          for(let x of this.totalfilter) {
            if(x["@NAME"] == 'local3' || x["@NAME"] == 'Local3') {
              x["@NAME"].hide(); //// this error i have no idea to hide this text
            }

          }
```

I want

```
my ion-option show           I want ion-option show
==================           ======================
book                         book
pen                          pen
school                       school
local3
```

Comment: I think you're asking how to modify an option's text. That would be done in the controller (on the data object), or it may be simpler to just use multiple options and toggle them as needed. At any rate, you shouldn't be showing and hiding anything in the view.

Comment: I want to hide some text because I want to save for user choose it, and sorry my english is not good

Comment: Please update your post to explain the scenario better. Describe the user interaction process.

Comment: I editted posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `filter` method and store the result in another list

```
public availableOptions: Array<any>;

// ...

this.totalfilter = data.json().FACETLIST.FACET;

// The next line will remove Local3, local3, LOCAL3, and so on (just in case)
this.availableOptions = this.totalfilter.filter(option => option["@NAME"].toLowerCase() !== 'local3');
```

And then use that property in your view

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="refine" (ionChange)="optionsFn(item, i);" >
    <ion-option [value]="item"  *ngFor="let item of availableOptions ;let i = index" >
       {{item["@NAME"]}}
    </ion-option>
 </ion-select>
```